# How to validate spaces between two words using regex in a string

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to validate string to accept spaces between two words (in the middle).

I want a regex that will accept "hello world".

I tried using `[\p{IsAlphabetic}\p{Digit}-_]{0,255}`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `\\w+\\s+\\w+` if you want to match two string separated by space(s).

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] testStrs = { "Hello", "Hello World", "123 456", "123456","Hello world good" };
        for (String s : testStrs) {
            System.out.println(s + " => " + s.matches("\\w+\\s+\\w+"));
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hello => false
Hello World => true
123 456 => true
123456 => false
Hello world good => false
```